# Compatibility problem with XNA

Tags: c#, windows-7, xna

I have a game in development in XNA 4.0 + Windows 7. On the Windows 7 OS the game runs with no problem but when I move the project on Win XP with .Net 4.0 installed the game doesn't work. What can be the problem?

Comment: Any sign of any error messages? This is a poor question. We are not psychic.

Comment: I suspect that you're not going to get any useful answers until you provide *a lot more detail* about what you're trying to do and about what actually happens when the game "doesn't work".

Comment: Maybe there is not xna 4.0 installed? Maybe the graphics card/directX is not able to do what you're trying to do. Does your app need DX10/DX11?

Comment: @x0n  i didn't give any more details because i didn't had any. As you can see in the picture, the error didn't give me any space to figure it out.
  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/zTVzs.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows Phone 7 Developer Beta Tools (which xna is a part of) don't work on windows xp. I think somewhere I read that there shall be a standalone version for xp with xna support only but I I'm not sure if this was already released *you might check out the apphub).

Comment: Question mentioned Windows 7, not Windows Phone 7. -1

Comment: i sure can read ;) xna 4 beta is part of the phone developer tools though. and the phone developer tools aren't for phone development only but contain vs2010, xna 4, silverlight tools and a phone emulator.

Comment: On a second thought this maybe wasn't clear: XNA 4 is currently  only shipped with the WPDT as they're beta. Once they're released there will be a XNA 4 standalone with XP support too (but no phone support then).

Comment: @Fge so for any game developed with xna, since xna has been reliesed, xna is a must? Or can you somehow integrate any used xna code in your game? and another question, do you know when the xna 4 stable version is due?

Regards,
Alex Badescu

Comment: From a system's point of view, xna is nothing different like let's say .net - a shared library. So your target pc must have it installed of course. Like .net applications don't run if .net isn't installed, neither do xna applications. I guess there are ways to include all xna code in your assembly but that's neither a good way of solving this problem nor the intention of shared librarys at all. I think XNA 4.0 was released a month ago but I'm not up2date with that tbh and I can only find the sdk version.